# vslam node crashes after some time

Tags: ros, vslam-system, vslam, stereo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running vslam on a stereo image data set , i am sending the 4 topics synchronously and also all the images are rectified and undistorted .I can see the camera trajectory and the point cloud in rviz .
but i have these 2 problems :

1. The point cloud in rviz shows some random trajectory of camera somewhere in between .
2. And after sometime the vslam node crashes saying.
   [Stereo VO] Inliers: 77  Nodes: 24   Points: 2484
   [NormRot] Bad quaternion: -nan -nan -nan -nan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10445/vslam-node-crashes-after-some-time-./) by [rajat](https://answers.ros.org/users/591/rajat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 175 on 2011-06-29

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rajat](https://answers.ros.org/users/591/rajat/) on 2011-07-05**:
i have some videos , i am not taking the feed from camera. , i split the whole thing into as many frames as possible and then also it's not working

**Comment by [ccm](https://answers.ros.org/users/604/ccm/) on 2011-07-05**:
Try moving your camera very slowly. My trajectory connects when I move my machine at the speed of a snail.

**Comment by [rajat](https://answers.ros.org/users/591/rajat/) on 2011-07-03**:
exactly :( , but it 's strange that it works absolutely correctly with the bag data .

**Comment by [ccm](https://answers.ros.org/users/604/ccm/) on 2011-07-03**:
I experienced that problem too. The trajectory goes haywire(especially when the camera makes a turn) and when the trajectory becomes too random the vslam node will crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The vslam node is experimental, so crashes will happen. ccm's comment is appropriate.  Patches are welcome.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1